Flutter error de version con google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0
Tengo la version de flutter: 3.22.3 • channel stable
Tengo un proyecto donde se pretende usar el paquete google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0.
En mi pubspeck.yaml lo tengo agregado de la siguiente forma:
name: hbapp
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.2+2

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.4 <4.0.0'    

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0 #actual version

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

Pero al querer correr la app, me sale este error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
   > There was a failure while executing work items
      > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
         > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
           Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
           Type io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: F:\projects\hubia2\build\webview_flutter_android\.transforms\59c60ff2c14b6cf9814c93048d213367\transformed\classes\classes.dex, F:\projects\hubia2\build\webview_pro_android\.transforms\9cf8db7253fc8e900f654f3e60e164e0\transformed\classes\classes.dex

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             37,8s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.            │
│ To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.      │
│ To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Este es mi build.gradle a nivel de proyecto:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23'  
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Este es mi build.gradle a nivel de app:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace "com.blogspot.hubiaapp"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hbaapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
introducir el código aquí

Tal error deja de aparecer solo cuando bajo la version a: google_mobile_ads: ^2.4.0 Compila bien y correctamente.
Evidentemente hay una relación con la version del paquete de google_mobile_ads ¿como podriamos solucionarlo?

La solución se basó en eliminar el paquete de flutter_webview_pro y usar webview_flutter ya que flutter_webview_pro me estaba generando conflictos a pesar de ser el unico paquete para webview que tenia.
Mi pubspeck.yaml:
  flutter_webview_pro: ^3.0.1+4 #eliminé este
  webview_flutter: ^4.8.0 #Lo reemplacé por este

Eso implicó el cambio del nombre del widget en el body
pasó de:
body: WebView( ...)

a
body WebViewWidget(...)

junto con la inicialización del respectivo controler.

El problema se debe a clases duplicadas:

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Type io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: F:\projects\hubia2\build\webview_flutter_android.transforms\59c60ff2c14b6cf9814c93048d213367\transformed\classes\classes.dex, F:\projects\hubia2\build\webview_pro_android.transforms\9cf8db7253fc8e900f654f3e60e164e0\transformed\classes\classes.dex

Para solucionar este problema, realiza una "exclusión" para evitar la repetición de esta clase, ve a tu archivo app/build.gradle y dentro del bloque de definición de dependencias, agrega la exclusión:
dependencies {
   implementation('io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter') {
        exclude group: 'io.flutter.plugins', module: 'webview_flutter_android'
    }
}


Pude resolver el problema eliminando el paquete de webview pro y usando solamente el paquete de webview
#flutter_webview_pro: ^3.0.1+4 Eliminé este
webview_flutter: ^4.8.0
Eso implicó tener que camibar widgets de nombre, por ejemplo el widget "WebView" al widget "WebViewWidget" junto con la incialización del controller.
